# Echo PHP based on form selection jQuery .post AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm using jQuery to send an AJAX request after a selection is made on a form, and I want echo back different things into a div depending on what selection is made. Here is my form:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="#">
   <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
      <option>-- Make a selection --</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
   </select>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript earlier in the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myselect').change(function() {
      $(this).parents("form").submit();
   });
   $('#myform').submit(function() { 
      $.post(
         'myscript.php',
         $(this).serialize(),
         function(data){
            $("#mydiv").html(data)
         }
      );
      return false;   
   });
});
```

And here is myscript.php:

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['myselect'] = "1") {
      echo "Div contents 1";
   }
   if ($_POST['myselect'] = "2") {
      echo "Div contents 2";
   }
?>
```

My problem is this: 'Div contents 1Div contents 2' gets echoed into mydiv after I make any selection on the form. I was trying to get it to echo 'Div contents 1' if option 1 is selected and 'Div contents 2' if option 2 is selected.

Thanks and apologies for the long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code :

```
 if ($_POST['myselect'] = "1")
```

and

```
 if ($_POST['myselect'] = "2") {
```

Will always evaluate to true, since its assignment.

You need to use :

```
  if ($_POST['myselect'] == "1") {
```

Comment: Argh such an obvious error! Many thanks for pointing it out anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Its a good oldy,

Change to

```
<?php
 if ($_POST['myselect'] == "1") {
  echo "Div contents 1";
 }
 if ($_POST['myselect'] == "2") {
  echo "Div contents 2";
 }
?>
```

Note the ==